# Is it more expensive to set a variable twice or once but inside an else block?

Tags: php

**Setting a variable twice**

```
$var = 2;
if ($someThing) {
    $var = 1;
}
```

*VS*

**Using an else**

```
if ($someThing) {
    $var = 1;
}
else {
    $var = 2;
}
```

I know that`$someThing` will get evaluated in both cases. `$var` Is also   going to be set in both cases. In the former it's set once then 50/50 chance to get set again. The later it's set only once, but there's an else block.

I was just curious if anyone has done any sort of testing with something similar. I know this is really micro-optimizing, but just a random thought that I had.

Comment: The simpler way to write it is `$var = $something ? 1 : 2;`

Comment: @barmar Yea, I'm aware of that. This was just a simple use case I wrote up. There may be more logic inside the if/else blocks, more assignments, etc...

Comment: Seriously, who downvotes this? It's a simple question that I was randomly curios about.

Comment: I would consider this "not useful" so i down voted it.

Comment: I don't know what causes people to downvote. Maybe they think you could have benchmarked this yourself, since you're so curious about it.

Comment: By considering something "not useful" you're essentially policing peoples curiosities.

Comment: i personally would never use the "expense" to determine which structure to use, that is what "useful" means to me here. All those who disagree should up-vote, that's the value of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the opcode steps for each option using the Vulcan Logic Dump

- [Option #1](https://3v4l.org/RNfu0/vld#tabs)

  ```
   compiled vars:  !0 = $var, !1 = $someThing
  line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 2
     4     1      > JMPZ                                                     !1, ->3
     5     2    >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 1
           3    > > RETURN                                                   1
  ```
- [Option #2](https://3v4l.org/S4spP/vld#tabs)

  ```
  compiled vars:  !0 = $someThing, !1 = $var
  line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3     0  E > > JMPZ                                                     !0, ->3
     4     1    >   ASSIGN                                                   !1, 1
           2      > JMP                                                      ->4
     7     3    >   ASSIGN                                                   !1, 2
           4    > > RETURN                                                   1
  ```
- and also using the [Ternary operator](https://3v4l.org/Xcl7H/vld#tabs)

  ```
  compiled vars:  !0 = $var, !1 = $someThing
  line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3     0  E > > JMPZ                                                     !1, ->3
           1    >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~2      1
           2      > JMP                                                      ->4
           3    >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~2      2
           4    >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, ~2
           5      > RETURN                                                   1
  ```

**EDIT**

As Barmar points out, not all methods execute all the steps, because there are jumps here, and not all steps have an equal processing cost either

Comment: According to those dumps, it looks like the later is more expensive, since there's 5 ops vs 4.

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov But some of them get skipped because of the jumps.

Comment: Code in bullet lists needs an extra level of indentation.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, thanks; one to remember for the future.... there's always something new to learn

Comment: That doesn't tell you which code is faster without interpretation since comparing the length of opcode instructions helps to optimize the program length which the OP didn't ask for. I don't see the point in looking at opcode (and this and other answers) at all!

Comment: @KarlRichter - so I guess the only useful answer from your perspective would have been to tell the OP to run some timing tests for themselves?

Comment: @MarkBaker No, just look at the code and figure what the program does like I did in my answer. You might formally analyse it as a GOTO program, but that shouldn't be necessary due to it's triviality.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about chance whether `$someThing` is fulfilled, but about the effort the machine has to make. Let's see:

```
$var = 2;
if ($someThing) {
    $var = 1;
}
```

means min. 1 assignment and 1 check and max. 2 assignments and 1 check.

```
if ($someThing) {
    $var = 1;
}
else {
    $var = 2;
}
```

means min. 1 assignment and 1 check and max. 1 assignment and 1 check.

The `else` is optimal.

Note: If `$someThing` depends on `$var` outside this piece of code and it is called repeatedly and want to be absolutely sure that your code is optimal you'll have to do an [amotized cost analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) which isn't too trivial.

Comment: Thanks! Putting it in those words makes more sense then the way I described it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to imagine it in assembly, which can differ based on architectures.

Here's some basic pseudocode:

```
write $var 2
bne $something x
write $var 1
x:
```

or

```
bne $something x
write $var 1
jmp y:
x:
write $var 2
y:
```

The first one has an extra write operation sometimes. The second one has an extra jump instruction sometimes. I would think that the jump instruction would be faster, and branch prediction would allow it to be optimised further under the hood, so I'd go for the second option.

Comment: It's difficult to say whether a statement is faster than another since PHP is an interpreted language. You would need to know both the OS and the hardware it run on to make such a statement.